What's the difference between いる, いた and no いる at all?
What's the difference between these sentences? What scenario do you use which of them?

すべての家具が部屋の一方の端に押し付けられている。
すべての家具が部屋の一方の端に押し付けられていた。
すべての家具が部屋の一方の端に押し付けられた。

